# Eclipse:make new folder in res folder

Tags: android, eclipse

i make new folder in res and new xml file like:

[image: make new folder]

but in my activity i can't use this xml file and folder.

make error in `R.sheikhoo.sheikhoo.xml` it's can not find `sheikhoo` in **R**

Comment: @FireCandyi want use new folder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot use custom name for your layout folder. Your layout folder should be like follows.

```
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml        // layout for small screen size
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

and for many more resource folder name refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: exactly.!! (y) perfect

Comment: its only for layout if you want to use video file in your project. place the video inside the "raw"(res->raw->video.mmp4) folder.

Comment: @Nas  i add raw folder in res and copy a video in it... but raw can find in R! `raw cannot be resolved or is not a field` when use `R.raw` ...

Answer (score 1):

you can't add folders with arbitrary names under `/res`. Android provides you the possibility to specify qualifiers (read more about them [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)), but custom names are not supported